# determining name of object loaded in R

Tags: r

Imagine you have an object `foo` that you saved as `saved.file.rda` as follows:

```
foo <- 'a'
save(foo, file='saved.file.rda')
```

Suppose you load `saved.file.rda` into an environment with multiple objects but forgot the name of the object that is in `saved.file.rda`.  Is there a way in R to determine that name?

You can do it the following way, which seems a little clunky:

```
bar <- load('saved.file.rda')
eval(parse(text=bar)) # this will pull up the object that was in saved.file.rda
```

However, is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Just to clarify: you want name of object (`"foo"`) or/and value of object (`"a"`)?

Comment: Marek, I'm interesetd in the name of the object so that I can refer to it later on.

Comment: Name of object is in your `bar` variable. So you can print it and see the name.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Assuming there is only one object saved in `saved.file.rda`, about:

```
bar <- load('saved.file.rda')
the.object <- get(bar)
```

or just:

```
bar <- get(load('saved.file.rda'))
```

If you want to be "neat" and not pollute your global workspace with the stuff you loaded (and forgot the name of), you can load your object into an environment, and specify that environment in you call to `get`.

Maybe:

```
temp.space <- new.env()
bar <- load('saved.file.rda', temp.space)
the.object <- get(bar, temp.space)
rm(temp.space)
...
```

Comment: Loading data to environment is different. Check my answer. You solution load data to global workspace. Do `ls()`.

Comment: Ah .. I meant to put `temp.space` as the second argument to `load`. Good catch (and edited to fix)

Answer (score 5):

As you can read in `?load` you can load data to specified environment. Then you could use `get` and `ls` to get what you want:

```
tmp_env <- new.env()
load('saved.file.rda', tmp_env)
get(ls(tmp_env), envir=tmp_env) # it returns only first object in environment
# [1] "a"
```

Answer (score 4):

well, i do know a function that eliminates the need to do that (i.e., find the name of the object in the R binary file you just loaded)--in other words, you can use this technique to load R binary files instead of 'load':

```
file_path = "/User/dy/my_R_data/a_data_set.RData"
attach(file_path, pos=2, name=choose_a_name, warn.conflict=T)
```

- 'warn.conflicts=T' is the default
  option
- 'pos=2' is also the default; "2"
  refers to the position in your search
  path. For instance, position 1 is
  ".GlobalEnv." To get the entire array
  of search paths, use **search**().  So
  you would access the search path for
  the new object by search()[2]
- use 'detach' to remove the object