# avoid load() to automatically name data frame

Tags: r

From the [load help page](http://127.0.0.1:26638/library/base/html/load.html):

```
## save all data
xx <- pi # to ensure there is some data

save(list = ls(all = TRUE), file= "all.RData")
rm(xx)

## restore the saved values to the current environment
local({
   load("all.RData")
   ls()
})

xx <- exp(1:3)
## restore the saved values to the user's workspace
load("all.RData") ## which is here *equivalent* to
## load("all.RData", .GlobalEnv)
## This however annihilates all objects in .GlobalEnv with the same names !
xx # no longer exp(1:3)
rm(xx)
attach("all.RData") # safer and will warn about masked objects w/ same name in .GlobalEnv
```

I was wondering: is there any way other than attaching data to prevent load() from "annihilating all objects in .GlobalEnv with the same names"? Thank you in advance

Comment: It's better to use RDS for storing and loading data (`readRDS`, `saveRDS`, etc). `attach` is really bad.

Comment: I want to avoid using attach, that's why the question

Comment: Right, so that's why I answered recommending RDS

Comment: right, makes sense :)

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5577221/how-can-i-load-an-object-into-a-variable-name-that-i-specify-from-an-r-data-file) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2520780/determining-name-of-object-loaded-in-r) somewhat related

Comment: As well you could create a new environment with 
newEnvironment<- new.env() 
and specify the environment in the load command, like load("all.rdata", envir=newEnvironment)